# Django logs colors depending on error level, without module

Tags: python, django, logging

I use the standard [Django logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/logging/) based on Python’s builtin logging module. My logging configuration in `settings.py` is close to the following:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '\x1b[33;21m{levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d}\x1b[0m: {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
        'sentry': {
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
            'tags': {'custom-tag': 'x'},
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'sentry'],
            'level': 'DEBUG' if DEBUG else 'WARNING',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to have ansi color (in this example, `\x1b[33;21m`) depending on `levelname` in the format, without installing additional modules like colorlog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this by subclassing `logging.Formatter` and changing the format according to the level by looking at the LogRecord object. The following code logs ERRORs in red and everything else in green. This is just a very basic example to give you an idea how this could work.

```
import logging

class LevelFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    def _set_format(self, fmt, style='%'):
         self._style = logging._STYLES[style][0](fmt)
         self._fmt = self._style._fmt

    def format(self, record):
        if record.levelno == logging.ERROR:
            self._set_format('\x1b[31;21m %(levelname)s \x1b[0m - %(message)s')
        else:
            self._set_format('\x1b[32;21m %(levelname)s \x1b[0m - %(message)s')
        return super().format(record)

fmt = LevelFormatter()

logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(fmt)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.error('error') # appears in red
logger.warning('warn') # appears in green
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I was hoping not to create a new logger though, and still use the logging configuration dictionary. I am trying to figure that out and mix it with your answer.

Comment: It's not necessary to create a new logger. You can attach your custom formatter with dictconfig. From the python docs: [In all cases below where a ‘configuring dict’ is mentioned, it will be checked for the special '()' key to see if a custom instantiation is required.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details)